# Formula to compute number of groups from given points (with overlap)

Tags: combinatorics, computer-science

The problem is kind of easy to understand.

Given is some points, say 10 points. (I am using numbering for understanding)

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

Now group these such that the group size is 5 and there is no overlap
so, there can be 2 groups. the groups are (0 1 2 3 4) & (5 6 7 8 9)

Now group the above given points such that the group size is 5 and overlap is 1
so, there can be 3 groups. the groups are (0 1 2 3 4) & (4 5 6 7 8) & (8 9) //Note: don't worry that (8 9) group has only 2 points

Now group the above given points such that the group size is 5 and overlap is 3
so, there can be 3 groups. the groups are (0 1 2 3 4) & (3 4 5 6 7 ) & (6 7 8 9)

I am looking for some generalized formula to compute the number of groups

So, given the group size and overlap size, find the number of groups. Can anyone help me with finding a generalized formula

Comment: `..such that the group size is 5` + `don't worry that (8 9) group has only 2 points` $$\quad$$ = $*$head asplode$*$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: removed answer to my complete misunderstanding. Added new response based on comment.

We t wish to compute the number of ways to find the number of "groups" over $n$ elements with $q$ overlap. Define $g$ to be the best-try group size. That should simply be $\lceil n / (g - q) \rceil$

So for your example we would have $n = 10$, $g = 5$ and $q = 1$. $\lceil 10 / (5 - 1) \rceil = \lceil 10/4 \rceil = \lceil 2.5 \rceil = 3$

Comment: I kinda understand what's going on but actually I need to find the value of k. All I know is n objects, number of objects in each partition and number of overlaps.

Comment: Ah I completely misunderstood. I appended the _correct_ answer.

Comment: In fact I needed to use this exact process for some calculation regarding some sequencing algorithms.